# fq_codel - does ath9k_htc support it

Tags: linux, networking, tc, traffic-shaping

I cannot seem to find documentation that says ath9k_htc supports fq_codel, so, it'd be safe to assume that it does not?  If I use fq_codel as the queue discipline and ath9k_htc doesn't support it, then does the system become unstable or fallback to fifo?

If it isn't available, then the next best (and easiest) option is to use htb?

Comment: I may be wrong, but isn't the scheduler implemented in software [in the kernel](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/sched/sch_fq_codel.c)? In this case, it should be supported by the driver?

Comment: Yes and no, I thought that too - the driver has to support that feature, hence why there is a page listing the drivers that support it.  It isn't listed, so I assume that it is NOT supported.

Comment: Not sure I can help more than this, but could you please provide a link to that page listing supported drivers? I feel curious about it.

Comment: https://www.bufferbloat.net/projects/bloat/wiki/BQL_enabled_drivers/

Comment: Ok thanks! There's also [this one](https://www.bufferbloat.net/projects/codel/wiki/Best_practices_for_benchmarking_Codel_and_FQ_Codel/) you surely saw already, and I ran the commands they used to list drivers supporting BQL on recent Linux sources, but it does not show anything about ath9_htc. So I suppose you're right and BQL is not supported at the moment. The page mentions emulating it with HTB indeed… Sorry, cannot help more than this :(

Comment: I appreciate the 2nd set of eyes, fq_codel looks great, but it isn't fully supported, so that is the Achilles heel which leads to making it a little more effort to achieve.